# Обработка GET-запросов на python: сохранить значение из одного запроса и отдать в другом

Tags: python, get, cgi, esp8266

Добрый день! Написал (точнее скопипастил) такой сервер:

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler
import time

server_address = ('192.168.0.198', 800)
httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
begin_time = time.asctime()
print('Server started on', begin_time)
print('Server is running on address', server_address[0], 'on port', server_address[1])
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Он принимает данные (GET-запрос) с платы ESP8266. Эти данные в консоли отображаются, но вот нормально их обработать не могу (хочу выводить на отдельной странице).

Что посоветуете?

UPD. С точки зрения пользователя должно быть так: зашел на 192.168.0.198:800/... и увидел окошко со значением температуры (её я и получаю get-запросом). На этом же адресе запущен сервер.

Comment: Более конкретно вопрос: как обработать get-запрос, который получает сервер (или просто какой модуль использовать для этого). Грубо говоря, с сервера мне нужно передать его на отдельную страницу. Искал похожие задачи, нашел пример обработки форм с использованием cgi, поэтому его и использовал. Если можно сделать проще, сообщите в каком направлении двигаться. Извините за неграмотность, я в этом деле начинающий :)

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Нет, просто микроконтроллер с датчиком температуры отправляет показания методом get на адрес 192.168.0.198:800, на котором и запущен сервер.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> микроконтроллер с датчиком температуры отправляет показания методом get

Чтобы создать http-сервер, который записывает температуру, полученную в GET запросе от микроконтроллера, и показывает её позже в последующих запросах, можно использовать [bottle библиотеку](http://bottlepy.org/docs/stable/):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from bottle import route, request, run, template # $ pip install bottle

temperature = None

@route('/')
def index():
    global temperature
    temperature = request.query.temperature or temperature
    return template('<b>Temperature: {{temperature}}</b>',
                    temperature=temperature)

run(host='localhost', port=8000)
```

При запуске этого Питон-скрипта, запускается http-cервер, который слушает на локальной машине на 8000 порту.

При получении GET-запроса, содержащего temperature параметр, глобальная переменная temperature обновляется и тут же показывается как html. Если temperature параметр не указан, то возвращается предыдущее значение или `None`, если ещё ни разу не был temperature параметр задан.

То есть ожидается, что часть читающая температуру с датчика выполняет запросы типа:

```
$ http ':8000?temperature=20'
```

что устанавливает значение (20).

Чтобы прочитать это значение, достаточно не указывать параметр:

```
$ http :8000
```

Можно в браузере посмотреть (тот же запрос):

```
$ python -mwebbrowser http://localhost:8000
```

<sup>`http` команду можно получить, установив [`httpie` библиотеку](https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie):</sup>

```
$ pip install httpie
```

Обычно вместо использования глобальных переменных используется база данных (что позволяет сохранять значение температуры между запусками серверного процесса или его экземплярами в разных процессах). В простейшем случае, простой плоский текстовый файл может использован. Вот [пример c sqlite](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#plugins).

Если не хочется ставить bottle с помощью команды (предпочтительно внутри virtualenv):

```
$ pip install bottle
```

то достаточно скачать [bottle.py](https://github.com/defnull/bottle/raw/master/bottle.py) и положить его рядом с кодом сервера.