# Постоянная работа приложения Python

Tags: python

Добрый день. Я сам недавно занимаюсь программированием и нахожусь только на начальной стадии. И ко мне время от времени приходят вопросы ответы на которые хотелось бы узнать, но кроме как к вам, мне некуда обратиться.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как заставить приложение работать постоянно?

Предыстория: у меня есть приложение которое следит за обновлениями в группе в контакте, как только появляется новая запись - она загружается в БД. Я запускаю приложение, оно пробегается по последним 10 записям и загружает те которых нет в базе и так каждый раз. Как мне сделать, что бы приложение работало постоянно и при добавлении записи в группе сразу подтягивалось в БД.

Comment: в сторону: вопросы на Stack Overflow обязаны допускать возможность краткого (несколько параграфов) ответа, то есть если хороший ответ на ваш вопрос требует гораздо большего объёма, то вопрос следует сузить или вам нужен другой ресурс. Ответы, состоящие только из ссылки на внешний ресурс (книгу, статьи) не слишком полезны: многие ссылки перестают работать спустя какое-то время и лучше если веб-поисковик в таких случаях напрямую будет людей, а не через Stack Overflow (то есть вопросы, на которые можно только ссылкой ответить, лучше удалить, чтобы гугл не смущать).

Comment: связанныевопросы [Как избежать вылета программы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/718136/23044), [Как выполнять код каждый день в заданное время](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/629442/23044)

Answer (score 3):

Здесь есть две части:

1. Приложение не выходит, выполнив одну задачу. К примеру, http-сервер продолжает работу после завершения обработки http-запроса
2. За приложением следит другая часть системы и если приложение падает/перестаёт на выбранный запрос отвечать, то выполняются действия по восстановлению. К примеру, `systemd`/`supervisord` могут перезапускать сервер, если его процесс умер.

Такие приложения часто в виде сервиса в системе устанавливаются (daemon). К примеру, это может быть http-сервер, который принимает callback, уведомляющий о создании новой записи.

Как правило в вашем коде вы не увидите глобального `while True` цикла, так как не имеет смысл реализовывать цикл событий в каждом приложении с нуля. Вот [пример кода для http-сервера—цикл событий запускается в `run()` методе, который не возвращается пока сервер не остановлен.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612741/23044)

Answer (score 2):

такой код:

```
while True:
    <...>
```

будет работать постоянно, пока программу принудительно не завершишь. вместо <...> конечно же надо написать саму программу.

Answer (score 2):

Лучше сделать так, чтобы не зависеть от времени и порядка запуска скрипта, тк постоянно работающий процесс это дополнительная сложность.

Просто перед вставкой в базу проверяйте что записи с таким заголовком там еще нет. Если есть, значит все новости дальше уже загружены и можно заканчивать.

Получится что скрипт можно запускать когда угодно и сколько угодно раз, а в базе всегда будут правильные данные.

Для запуска скриптов по расписанию обычно используют cron, например так можно запускать скрипт update_news.py каждые 10 минут:

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/local/bin/update_news.py
```

Comment: у автора требование, чтобы изменения сразу отображались: *"при добавлении записи в группе сразу подтягивалось в БД."* cron вариант требует постоянных запусков (вне зависимости, есть новые записи/нет) и информация может отставать (в зависимости от интервала запуска). Чтобы избежать задержки и ненужных сетевых запросов, можно webhook настроить, который вызывается  при добавлении новых записей, или другой способ, который информацию сразу доставляет. Сравните скрипт, который из cron содержимое директории читает в поисках нового файла, c демоном, который inotify использует; или как websockets на SO

Comment: "Добрый день. Я сам недавно занимаюсь программированием и нахожусь только на начальной стадии" Судя по этому, демон это слишком сложно. Да и вообще в подобной задаче задержка в минуту должна быть приемлемой, городить огород из демонов совершенно ни к чему.

Comment: Для совсем начинающего, достаточно в консоле руками [скрипт со сервером запустить](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612741/23044), что ещё проще чем в cron скрипт прописывать (по статистике совсем начинающие вероятно на Windows сидят)¶ В целом, ответы на SO предназначены не только для автора, поэтому в любом случае cron может быть только дополнением, но не основным ответом по теме *"Постоянная работа приложения Python"*