# Как избежать вылета программы

Tags: python, python-3.x, исключения, обработка-ошибок, try-catch

Можно ли используя конструкцию try-except заставить программу перезапускаться при любой возможной ошибке, а не вылетать? Возможности указать все коды ошибок нет.

Comment: «Возможности указать все коды ошибок нет.» — почему нет? У вас помимо исключений (абсолютно все исключения можно поймать в except) есть ещё какие-то ошибки, которые except'ом не ловятся что ли?

Comment: @andreymal есть сигналы

Comment: @jfs есть, но с близкой к единице вероятностью под страшным сочетанием «любая возможная ошибка» имеются в виду банальные исключения, наследующиеся от Exception

Answer (score 7):

"При любой возможной ошибке" может включать и [segfault](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8). То есть, скрипт может по сигналу умереть. [`faulthandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/faulthandler.html) может напечатать traceback при получении сигнала.

`except:` (с пустым спецификатором исключения) любое исключение ловит. Есть также `sys.excepthook` для непойманных исключений. Вы можете их использовать, чтобы записать в логи подробное сообщение об ошибке.

Так как скрипт может быть убит таким образом, что он никакие действия не успеет предпринять, то следует использовать *внешнюю* программу для перезапуска скрипта, к примеру, systemd/supervisord.

Если вы хотите, чтобы программа постоянно работала, то можно сделать её системным сервисом.

Answer (score 5):

вы можете использовать `supervisor` или `runit` чтобы он сам перезапускал программу если она упадет.
Как минимум логирование ошибок будет полезно в любом случае