# Сохранение ошибок в файл, если программы была закрыта из-за них

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, cx-freeze

Можно ли в python как нибудь создать файлик.txt, куда буду сохраняться возникающие ошибки если программы была закрыта из-за них?

Comment: Модуль `logging`

Comment: @Alban а конкретнее сам код вывода именно названия ошибки `logger.info('ПРИВЕТ)` вместо привет что писать?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как избежать вылета программы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/718136/23044)

Comment: связанный вопрос [Logging uncaught exceptions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6234405/4279)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import sys, traceback

def excepthook(*args):
    try:
        exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb = args
    except:
        exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()

    traceback.print_exception(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb, file=sys.stdout)
    with open('файлик.txt', 'a') as log:
        traceback.print_exception(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb, file=log)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.excepthook = excepthook
    assert False, 'err text'
```